# MsWord VBA Jumping on Heading by Name

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I'm adding an internal link in Word VBA (ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add)
I can refer to a Heading as **SubAddress:="_MyHeadingName"**
If you click on the link it jumps there fine.
This is a proof, that in Word, Headings are quasi Bookmarks.

However:
I cannot figure how to jump on a specific heading in VBA if I want to.
(Without using Find + .style parameter)
I would expect something like

```
Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToHeading, Name:="_MyHeadingName" 'OR "MyHeadingName"
```

Or

```
Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="_MyHeadingName" 'OR "MyHeadingName"
```

To work and put selection on that specific Heading.
... but it does not...

**Any ideas? (Why not, How yes, What is better approach)**

---

**EDIT (Summary of conclusions so far):**

It is possible to jump on a HeadingName using: `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(_HeadingName).Select`, but only if prior to that at least a hyperlink or a hidden-bookmark was created pointing to that heading (see the discussion for examples to both)

Comment: Can you describe a scenario where you'd want to do that? In some detail, as in how you'd inform VBA to which heading it should go and in what way such a macro would be useful. I'm having difficulty imagining how the Navigation pane, or cross-references or ToC aren't sufficient...

Comment: This macro automates the process of adding a keyword collection to a document, under a specific heading name. the position of the heading is dynamic, so i cant refer by number, only by name. I CAN jump on it with Find + style , just wanted to know if also possible by something like Goto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick 'n' easy...

Add this function to a module:

```
Sub jumpToBookmark(bmName As String)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bmName).Select
    Application.Selection.Collapse
End Sub
```

Then call it like:

```
jumpToBookmark "myBookmark"
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Bookmarks Object** (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/bookmarks-object-word)
- MSDN : [**Selection.Collapse Method** (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/selection-collapse-method-word)

Comment: this sounds promising i hope that works for heading names as well as expected. Im on a short trip now, on monday i will report back.

Comment: "Heading names" as in a text formatted with a `HeadingStyle`?  (or, heading is also bookmarked, it will find it by the bookmark name)

Comment: As described in the other comment: When you create a link, you can see, that HeadingStyles are automatically referenced independent of bookmarks. So mydoc.doc #MyHeadingName is understood out of the box. I want to use that feature for other purposes now within the VBA code, to jump on specific headings without creating a bookmark! Seems logical to be possible, but dont yet know the working method.

Comment: i was so excited that i borrowed a laptop while traveling, just to test this. And it works!! I confirm, that Without creating any prior Bookmarks, Activedocument.Bookmarks("_MyHeadingName").select is jumping to the specified Heading name.

Comment: Sorry, I need to remove the GreenTick, because as #macropod pointed out in his comments , this reference only works if a hidden bookmark was created before - when a link was created to it somewhere.

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki - I'm confused - you said you tested it and you confirmed that it worked?  Your question did not say anything about when/how/why the bookmarks are created.  Did my answer not solve the question as posted? Besides, it worked fine work me with (invisible) bookmarks that I added, both through the Bookmarks interface, and using `Bookmarks.Add`.

Comment: Rightful confusion, the tick goes back as it solves the "BaseCase". My point was to find a way that is simpler then using .Find and works out of the box. IF I need to create a bookmark (even if it is hidden) before I can jump on a Heading, the process is not lighter then using Find. I truly said I have tested it, but I was not aware at that point, that prior to my test the Hidden Bookmarks were created already, and that made me beleive that it worked Without creating a bookmark. Sorry for my mistake! - I will now wright all the conclusions in my Question post as well + you get the reward back.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the Find code more compact, you could use:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting: .Style = wdStyleHeading1: .Execute FindText:="MyHeadingName", Format:=True
End With
```

Comment: Yes, this is a "quasi one-liner" :) 
I think not even "Format" is needed, bare minimum as oneliner is: 
With MyRange.Find: .ClearFormatting: .Text = "MyHeadingName": .Style = wdStyleHeading1:  .Execute: End With

Answer (score 2):

Word only adds a (hidden) bookmark to a Heading once it is referenced (e.g. for a cross-reference or Table of Contents), and a different bookmark is added for each kind of reference (e.g. _Ref510330670 for a cross-reference and _Toc467495364 for a Table of Contents entry for the same heading).

If you want to go to a particular Heading, you can use Find, specifying the heading text and/or the heading Style. In any event, you shouldn't need to use Selection for any of this - you can almost always address the ranges directly.

If you're wedded to using Selection.Goto, you'll need to work with what Word supports. Unless you know that the heading has been bookmarked - and what that bookmark's name is - then, as described in the VBA help file, you could use either of:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToFirst
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=1
```

If you know the heading's bookmark name you could use:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bookmarkname"
```

where you supply the bookmark's name in place of 'bookmarkname'.

Comment: Im not married to Select, just used it in the example. My confusion roots in the following: When creating link "c:\ folder\documentdoc #HeadingName" in VBA works for me out of the box. Now i wanted to do a similar thing, but  instead of creating a link, i wanted to jump there by the macro, to perform some further automated editing , but i could not make VBA to make a similar Jump on its own.  So looking for the simplest whatever way to do that.

Comment: As I said: "If you want to go to a particular Heading, you can use Find, specifying the heading text and/or the heading Style."

Comment: We knew about the find method, i have also mentioned it in my original post, but you might be interested in the final outcome of this research: you can simply use Activedocument.Bookmarks("_MyHeadingName") to jump on any specific heading, without using Find.

Comment: I am well aware of Activedocument.Bookmarks - but you can't use that on a heading unless it has a bookmark (and not all may have one) and you know what that bookmark's name is...

Comment: Now im curious. please try for yourself the method i just described above! For me it was working without creating a bookmark, simply putting _ before the name. How is it for you?

Comment: A bookmark whose name begins with _ is a hidden bookmark. If you have such a bookmark with a heading name, that's because the bookmark was created before you used ActiveDocument.Bookmarks - when you previously created a hyperlink pointing to the heading.

Comment: :( I regret to inform... unfortunately you were right. I have double checked the scenario, and the hidden bookmark only existed, because in some other document there was a reference to it. This is a shame, so it seems there is no easy way.
Is this the most compact use of Find to achieve the same? : 
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "MyHeaderName"
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
    .Execute
End With
Note: I have tried as oneliner, using .find.Execute ("what", ... , "WhatStyle") , but .execute does not include Style parameter...